# Atualizar campo em diversas colunas

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu tenho uma lista de categorias e eu gostaria de classificá-los todos de uma vez, então eu criei um campo de "ordenação", onde eu posso colocar o número da ordem que eu quero [1] e assim por apertar para salvar [2] como o imagem:

[image]

```
//Controller: administracao.php
function update_ordenacao(){
        $this->load->model("administracao_model");

        $ordemCat = array (
            // coluna                                   // campo form
            "id_categoria_anuncio"              =>      $this->input->post("id_categoria_anuncio"),
            "page_id_categoria_anuncio"         =>      $this->input->post("ordenacao"),
        );

        $sucesso = $this->administracao_model->ordenacaoCats($ordemCat);

        if($sucesso) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("success", "Ordem alterada com sucesso!");
            redirect("administracao/ver_cat_anuncios");
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata("danger", "A ordem das categorias não pode ser alterada!");
            redirect("administracao/ver_cat_anuncios");
        }


    }
```

**Model:**

```
// Model: administracao_model.php
function ordenacaoCats($ordemCat){

            $data = array(
                array(
                  'id_categoria_anuncio'            => $ordemCat['id_categoria_anuncio'] ,
                  'page_id_categoria_anuncio'       => $ordemCat['page_id_categoria_anuncio']
                )
            );    

            $this->db->update_batch('categorias_anuncios', $data, 'id_categoria_anuncio'); 
            //echo $this->db->last_query();


    }
```

**View:**

```
//View: ver_cat_anuncios.php

                    <?php echo form_open("administracao/update_ordenacao", array('id' =>'categorias-dos-anuncios')); ?>
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>Nome da Categoria</th>
                            <th>Ordenação <?php  echo form_button(array( "class"      => "btn-ordenacao fa fa-floppy-o",  "content"    => "",  "type" => "submit" )); ?></th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Ações</th>
                        </tr>

                        <?php if (count($categorias)) : foreach ($categorias as $categoria) :?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?=$categoria['id_categoria_anuncio']; ?></td>
                            <?php ($categoria['is_parent_categoria_anuncio'] !== "0") ? $espacamento = " " : $espacamento = "- "; ?>

                            <td><?= anchor('administracao/edit_cat_anuncios/' .$categoria['id_categoria_anuncio'], $espacamento.$categoria['titulo_categoria_anuncio']);?></td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <?= form_hidden('id_categoria_anuncio', $categoria['id_categoria_anuncio']);?>
                                    <?= form_input(array(
                                        "name"          =>  "ordenacao",
                                        "value"         =>  $categoria['page_id_categoria_anuncio'],
                                        "id"            =>  "ordenacao",
                                        "class"         =>  "form-control",
                                        "maxlength"     =>  "3",
                                        "style"         =>  "width: 60px; text-align: center;"
                                    )); ?>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php if($categoria['show_menu_categoria_anuncio'] == 1) {echo "<span style=\"color: #009202; font-weight: bold;\">Ativado</span>";} else {echo "<span style=\"color: #e10707; font-weight: bold;\">Desativado</span>";} ?> </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Ações">
                                    <?= btn_edit('administracao/edit_cat_anuncios/'. $categoria['id_categoria_anuncio'] );?>
                                    <?= btn_delete('administracao/deleta_cat_anuncios/'. $categoria['id_categoria_anuncio'] );?>                                    
                                </div>                              
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5"><p class="text-info">Não há nenhuma categoria no sistema!</p></td>
                            </tr>

                        <?php endif;?>
                    </table>
                    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Este meu código eu fiz dando uma olhada na documentação do CodeIgniter

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'My date 2'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name 2' ,
      'date' => 'Another date 2'
   )
);

$this->db->update_batch('mytable', $data, 'title'); 

// Produces: 
// UPDATE `mytable` SET `name` = CASE
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My Name 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another Name 2'
// ELSE `name` END,
// `date` = CASE 
// WHEN `title` = 'My title' THEN 'My date 2'
// WHEN `title` = 'Another title' THEN 'Another date 2'
// ELSE `date` END
// WHERE `title` IN ('My title','Another title')
```

O que será que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Você só não falou o que está dando errado.

Comment: Oi! A tela fica toda branca.. olho o código fonte e não tem nada..
Na verdade para ver a tela branca eu tive que tirar o "if($sucesso) ....

Comment: Não entendi qual o seu problema nem seu erro! Será que tem como colocar mais detalhes.

Comment: Se você quer submeter vários elementos de uma vez que são iguais, vc tem que colocar `name="ordenacao[]"` e capturar no foreach `$_POST['ordenacao']`.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você está querendo salvar a ordenação que colocar para cada item (categoria), mas o primeiro erro que vejo é na sua view. Deve colocar o nome e id do campo com []

```
<?= form_input(array(
    "name"          =>  "ordenacao[]",
    "value"         =>  $categoria['page_id_categoria_anuncio'],
    "id"            =>  "ordenacao[]",
    "class"         =>  "form-control",
    "maxlength"     =>  "3",
    "style"         =>  "width: 60px; text-align: center;"
)); ?>
```

não sei como esta sendo enviado esses dados para o controller, mas imagino que por um js, dai você deve pegar esses dados `$this->input->post("ordenacao")` e fazer um loop nesses dados e dai fazer o `update_batch`.

Da forma que fez, para não ter que alterar o seu controller e somente o seu model ficaria algo assim:

```
function ordenacaoCats($ordemCat){

    $data = array();

    foreach ($ordemCat['page_id_categoria_anuncio'] as $ord) {
        $data[] = array(
                'id_categoria_anuncio'      => $ordemCat['id_categoria_anuncio'] ,
                'page_id_categoria_anuncio' => $ord
            );
    }    

    $this->db->update_batch('categorias_anuncios', $data, 'id_categoria_anuncio'); 
    //echo $this->db->last_query();


}
```

Lembre-se, não tenho como testar aqui, mas essa é a ideia.

Comment: Creio que esteja certo, não sabia que eu teria que mandar como uma Array, mas pensando por esse lado está certo o seu modo. Só não tem como eu testar agora pois estou fora esta semana.

Só tem uma coisa. Os dados estão sendo enviados normalmente através de um submit que é o botão com o numero 2 do lado na imagem... se tiver que enviar através de um Js já não sei como fazer..rs 

Vou verificar se o código está certo quando eu retornar e então te respondo/avalio :)

Mas desde já quero te agradecer pela ajuda.

Comment: Olá Marcelo! Tudo bom?
Desculpe a demora em responder. Como disse não estaria próximo do código durante a semana. 
Testei agora e infelizmente não deu certo o código. Não sei ainda se fiz algo de errado, mas acabou que eu consegui fazendo um for e tirando o update_batch e colocando um update comum mesmo... 
Bom, deu certo..

Obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Comment: Então Vitor, o lado ruim da forma que fez é que a cada iteração irá executar o update e quando tiver muitos registros para fazer o update irá demorar um pouco mais, e vc saberia dizer o que não deu certo no código?

Comment: Não sei se fiz certo, mas tentei várias combinações de variaveis no codigo que você me passou. 
Mas para o projeto que eu estou fazendo não haverá muitas categorias. e isso será feito no administrador de vez em quando e somente quando precisar colocar uma categoria nova que precise ir outro lugar que não seja em ultimo.

Enfim... infelizmente eu já não conhecia o "batch" em si fora do codeigniter, pois infelizmente tem pouco tempo que estou estudando programação... Então ainda estou aprendendo aos poucos o que posso fazer ou não com a linguagem.

Obrigado pela força mais uma vez! :)